# chain functions directly to newly created object instance in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my ongoing saga to understand more about Object Oriented Javascript - I came across a question about creating a class to respond to the following API:

```
var foo = new bar().delay(750).start().then(onComplete);

var bar = function() {
    this.delay(function(per) {
      //...
    };
}
```

Can someone with more experience than me please describe how to create class that would respond to this? I have never seen chaining like this and can't find any information online :(

Comment: This is called [*fluent interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) through [*method chaining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This chaining is accomplished by returning `this` in your functions :

```
this.delay = function(per) {
  //...
  return this;
};
```

If you want to stick to first line code, then your constructor should be named bar :

```
var bar = function() {
    this.delay = function(per) {
      //...
      return this;
    };
    this.start = function() {
      ...
      return this;
    };
}
```

See [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/pLCXM/) (open the console)

Answer (score 1):

The secret to method chaining is to return `this` from each method that you want to be able to chain with.  That allows the next method to be `this.method()` automatically.  Your definition of the bar object would look something like this shell:

```
function bar() {
    // bar initialization code here
}

bar.prototype = {
    delay: function(amt) {
        // delay code here
        return(this);
    },
    start: function() {
        // start code here
        return(this);
    },
    then: function(fn) {
        // then code here
        fn();
        return(this);
    }
};


var foo = new bar().delay(750).start().then(onComplete);
```

In your example, `new bar()` is executed and it returns a pointer to the new `bar` object.
Using that new object pointer, the `.delay(750)` method is called on that object.  That method then also returns the object so the `.start()` method is called on the return value from `.delay(750)` which is still the same object and so on...